# Passing props to<nuxt-link> or pass hidden data to router but not using parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Currently, I'm using nuxt and vue routing for my web app.

in my view I'm my link like this:
`<nuxt-link :to="'/article/' + article.id">`

subsequently, I'm using this article ID on my article page by requesting the parameter from the URL do make my API request:
`${params.id}`

This works fine but my URL ends up like this: article/1 but I want to start using user-friendly URL's like article/this-is-my-article but I still need to pass the article id.

Is there a way to pass this ID to nuxt-link with a prop or is there any other way to pass this id 'invisible' so I can use it to ake my API call?

Comment: Did you find a working solution to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the $router with params instead nuxt-link to do you want, I think.
Here my suggestion.

```
<div@click="$router.push({name:'[goal name]', params:{[params]}})" >View All History</div>
```

exmaple here.

```
<div @click="$router.push({name:'view_tables-display_reports', params:{id:'pie'}})" >View All History</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried this and it adds the id to my URL! So that's good! I really didn't want the id in my URL but I guess there is no other choice

Comment: okay! But on my side the params are not included into my URL!

Comment: Why not to use <nuxt-link> when the goal is to change to other page? Links are meant for that.

Answer (score 2):

I Suggest that instead of id create a new field in your table and name it slug with unique() then use this as identifier so it will be more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `<Nuxt-Link>` with a *named route* and *params*

With this, params will not be exposed in the URL, and depending on how you have your router setup, they'll be passed into equivalent props in the component loaded for the route, ie: a route param `id` will pass into a component prop `id`.

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'MyArticleRoute', params: { id: id } }">
 View Article
</nuxt-link>
```